# choosing pixel size for kernel density estimate map (density.ppp) in r

Tags: r, spatial, kernel-density, spatstat

I have a shapefile of polygons and a shapefile of points that are distributed within the polygons. I've created kernel density estimate (KDE) maps for each polygon based on the points it contains using the density.ppp function from the `spatstat` package.
I now wish to create different kde's with different pixel sizes in order to chose the one that best suits my model. I tried using the eps argument in the `as.mask` function, but that only changed the pixel size of the window and not of the kernel map itself so the results did not change.
after going throw the entire manual of the density.ppp function, all I was able to find that looked related was the `pixellate.ppp` function from the `spatstat.geom` package, but i'm not sure how to use it with the `density.ppp`.

Any suggestion how to change the pixel size of the kde's?

```
library(sf)
library(spatstat)

buffer <- st_read("gis/layers/buffers.shp")
pbb<- st_read("gis/layers/points_by_buffer.shp")

for (p in 1:10) {
 if(p %in% pbb$field_id) {
   
   poly123 <- pbb[pbb$field_id == p,]
   
   C <- as.owin(buffer$geometry[p])

   W<- as.mask(C, eps = 100)

   point<- ppp(poly123$X,poly123$Y, window = W)

   sigma <- bw.diggle(point)
   
   d <- density.ppp(point, kernel = "gaussian", sigma=sigma, positive = TRUE, at="pixels", )
   plot(d) 
}
```

Comment: The density is not the number of points in a pixel. The density is the number of points per unit area --- the number of points in one square unit --- using the physical unit of length in which the spatial coordinates are expressed. If the coordinates are in metres, the density values are "number of points per square metre". See longer answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three different things:

- **resolution**: the spacing between the grid points at which the density will be calculated.
- **bandwidth**: the amount of smoothing that will be applied to the input data.
- **unit of length**: the physical unit of length (e.g. metre, kilometre); the units in which the spatial coordinates are given; the density values are expressed using the same units (density is the number of points per square unit).

If you change the *resolution* (which you can do using the arguments `eps` or `dimyx` in the call to `density.ppp`), the values of density will not change very much; you are just changing the spacing of the locations where the density is calculated.

If you change the *bandwidth* (which you can do by using the arguments `sigma` and `adjust` in the call to `density.ppp`), the values of density will change substantially. When you increase the bandwidth, each data point is effectively spread over a greater distance, and the density estimate becomes smoother and flatter.

If you change the *unit of length*, everything will change by a scale factor. The values of density are "number of points per unit area". If the density value is 3, this means we expect to see an average of 3 points per square unit. Here the 'unit' is the unit of length in which the spatial coordinates are expressed. If the original point coordinates are expressed in metres, then the density values are 'number of points per square metre'. If you want to change this, there are two ways:

- **rescale the input data** (recommended): for example if the original data coordinates are in metres, you could convert them to kilometres by dividing the coordinates by 1000. We recommend using the function `rescale.ppp` to do this: `Xnew <- rescale(Xold, 1000)`. You can declare the *name* of the unit of length using the function `unitname` (as in `unitname(Xnew) <- "km"`), or using `rescale.ppp` (as in `Xnew <- rescale(Xold, 1000, "km")`). After rescaling the point pattern, you invoke `density.ppp` (as in `Dnew <- density(Xnew, ...)` *with the bandwidth expressed in kilometres*) and the resulting density values are expressed in points per square km.
- **rescale the result** (not recommended): if your coordinates were in metres and you decide later that you wanted to know the density expressed in points per square kilometre, then you could just apply the scaling factor to the image (by typing `Dnew <- D * 1000^2` where `D` is the original density image) and also rescaling the spatial coordinates of the image (by typing `Dnew <- rescale(Dnew, 1000, "km")`). We don't recommend this because it is easy to mess up.

See [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the pixel size only changes the resolution of the result, but the underlying math is the same. It is just a question about how fine the resulting grid is. You can change this by using the arguments `eps` or `dimyx` in your call to `density.ppp()`. This is of course relevant, but to a large degree the answer is just: Finer resolution is better (or at least usually not worse unless you go to the extreme and hit numerical instabilities). Finer resolution makes a plot of the estimated intensity look nicer, but maybe this is not what you want when you say you want "to chose the one that best suits my model". It is usually much more interesting to see the effect of the chosen smoothing bandwidth specified by `sigma`. You have just fixed this by using Diggle's rule, but this is in no way an established "best practice". Actually choosing bandwidth is a problem with no easy universal solution. You could try a range of different bandwidths and see which one seems best for your purpose. The pixel resolution should just be high enough for the plot to look nice and low enough for the calculation not to take too long.

Comment: Thank toy Ege for the answer. if you could see the comment above and address that I would very much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing "resolution" with "bandwidth".

The pixel resolution refers to the size of the pixels in the output - effectively the spacing of the grid points at which the intensity estimate will be computed. This spacing does not matter very much, for most purposes.

"Bandwidth" is the degree of smoothing applied to the data. A large bandwidth will produce a relatively flat surface, while a small bandwidth will produce a highly peaked surface. The bandwidth does have a big effect, and it needs to be chosen appropriately for the data.

The pixel resolution is controlled by the arguments `eps` and `dimyx` which can be passed to `density.ppp`. (Admittedly it is hard to read this from the help files but `help(density.ppp)` mentions that the unmatched arguments `...` are passed to `pixellate.ppp`, and `help(pixellate.ppp)` mentions that the unmatched arguments `...` are passed to `as.mask`, and finally the help for `as.mask` describes the arguments `eps` and `dimyx`. That's just how argument passing works in R.)

The smoothing bandwidth is controlled by the argument `sigma`. See `help(density.ppp)` for information on how to select and control the smoothing bandwidth. Also read the "See Also" section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I understand what the resolution and the bandwidth means in this case. what I meant is that I want to change the way the density is calculated. If the density is the number of point per area unit, I want to change the area unit size. is this at all possible?

Comment: It sounds like the resolution should do it by adjusting the '''eps'', but the results I get (the kde values) stay the same.

Comment: Density is the number of points per unit area. If the spatial coordinates of the point pattern are given in metres, then the density values are the number of points per square metre. To change this to number of points per square KILOmetre, you would rescale the point pattern coordinates by changing `X` to `Y <- rescale(X, 1000, "km")` and then apply `density(Y)`. The bandwidth would also have to be expressed in km. See the help for `rescale.ppp` and `unitname<-.ppp`